# PHP equivalent of Date.UTC function in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, date, timestamp, utc

I'm fetching dates from MySQL as strings (`Y-m-d` format). I need to display a chart using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Highcharts uses javascript [`Date.UTC`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp) function:

> Return the number of milliseconds between a specified date and
>   midnight January 1 1970.

```
data: [
    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
```

But i'd like to avoid javascript and do in in PHP (assigning a JSON object - the chart - to the page itself). What's the equivalent of `Date.UTC` function in PHP (regardless the server datezone)?

```
$date      = '2012-07-07';
$millisecs = 1000 * unix_timestap_utc_regardless_server_zone($date);
```

Comment: From PHP to JS, put this in a variable: `date('Y, n-1, j-1', strtotime($date));` and echo out `Date.UTC($var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');    
$today = date(getdate());
```

That would set $today as the date.

EDIT: Niclas is also right, this is just how I would do it.

EDIT 2: You can replace getdate() with a valid timestamp in PHP, if you like...

EDIT 3: Sorry... Misunderstanding... use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to make a valid timestamp!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks. But (for example) strtotime is going to use the time zone specified in my PHP.ini, right?

Comment: strtotime is only going to use defult timezone if you dosn't provide one your self, like `strtotime("00:00:00 UTC")`

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the PHP Timestamp and then convert into Javascript Timestamp with a *multiplication*

```
$phpTimestamp = $dateObject->getTimestamp();
$javascripTimestamp = $phpTimestamp * 1000;
```